# Output via HDMI only, not laptop screen

Tags: nvidia, display

Dell XPS 17 on 14.04 using Nvidia drivers, was working fine, but now only shows output on the screen connected via HDMI connection, and not the laptop screen. There's output on the laptop screen when its booting etc, so I know it still works ok, but neither the 'Settings > Display' tool, Nvidia-settings, or xrandr detects the laptop screen anymore.

eg

buddha:~> xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 337mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     50.0     60.1     60.0     50.0
   1680x1050      60.0
   1600x900       60.0
   1440x900       59.9
   1400x1050      60.0
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0
   1280x800       59.8
   1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0
   1152x864       75.0
   1024x768       75.0     60.0
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   720x576        50.0
   720x480        59.9
   640x480        75.0     59.9     59.9

Any way to 'reset' this so that it detects the inbuilt screen again?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Eventually the most obvious thing helped, pressing the 'FN screen key' several times brought my laptop screen back. It suddenly happened after pressing it about ten times, every time with waiting a few seconds in between.

Comment: Tried that, no luck. If there's no other suggestions I might try revert back to nouveau and see if that makes any difference.